# LLVM: Cannot get vmjc to work

Tags: java, llvm, emscripten

I'd like to compile Java to Javascript with LLVM like this:

- *.java to *.class, via Oracle's javac
- *.class to *.bc, via vmkit's vmjc
- *.bc to *.html with JS, via emscripten's emcc

The created HTML/JS file (about 170KB large) prints `ReferenceError: _StartJnjvmWithoutJIT is not defined` in the browser console when opened. Trying to debug this I noticed that the *.bc file (LLVM IR) doesn't even seem to contain my code, i.e. the strings I'm printing are not inside.

What I did:

```
vmjc -disable-opt -main=MyTest MyTest.class
```

It prints out, no matter whether I use Java 6 or 7:

```
WARNING: Class file 'java/lang/VMString' requires Java version 1.7. This JVM only supports Java versions up to 1.6.
```

It creates a `*.bc` file anyway. When I convert that to non-binary (`*.ll`), I get a file where I would have expected my strings that I print to appear, but they don't. A string like `MyTest_main` does appear there, though:

```
llvm-dis MyTest.class.bc
```

So, is this approach viable at all? What does the warning about the Java version mean? Why doesn't my 'hello world' string appear in the `*.ll` code and is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten the route by using GWT to compile Java directly to JavaScript.

Comment: Have you actually tried that, i.e. compiling any Java code (not just GUI code for the Web) to Javascript using GWT?

Comment: I once used the Antlr runtime in a GWT-based project, and it worked well. However, the GWT compiler needs Java source code, it won't work if you just have compiled .class-files. Also, GWT does not (fully) support all classes provided by Java's runtime environment: For instance, you can't use AWT or Swing, several IO-related classes (like java.io.File) aren't supported, and sometimes not all methods of a class are available (For instance, there is no support for Collections.shuffle() in GWT).

Comment: @Daniel: The GWT compiler itself is not GUI-related at all. Yes, you can only transform Java sources directly. The result is well optimized JavaScript code. Integration to existing JavaScript is still a littly clumsy. And yes, many Java libs are not available (especially those that have no equivalent in the browser world, such as files, streams, threads, ..). Here is a list of what is supported: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html

Answer (score -2):

Java and JavaScript are two different languages. Cross-compiling is tricky and mostly leads to clumsy code.

Personally I recommend a manual reimplementation of the core logic in Typescript, because it supports classical OO (object-oriented) development and type safety. Translating the code this way is time consuming, but relatively easy.

Alternatively, OO-style programming in native JavaScript is also possible. But since it lacks type savety, development this way is harder. 
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/